# Five Porismatic Equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, contest-math

Here is a really tough problem.

If

$$\boldsymbol{a\cos\alpha\cos\beta+b\sin\alpha\sin\beta+c=0}$$
$$\boldsymbol{a\cos\gamma\cos\delta+b\sin\gamma\sin\delta+c=0}$$
$$\boldsymbol{a\cos\beta\cos\gamma+b\sin\beta\sin\gamma+c=0}$$
$$\boldsymbol{a\cos\delta\cos\epsilon+b\sin\delta\sin\epsilon+c=0}$$
$$\boldsymbol{a\cos\epsilon \cos\alpha+b\sin\epsilon\sin\alpha+c=0}$$

prove that

$$\boldsymbol{\frac{1}{a^3}+\frac{1}{b^3}+\frac{1}{c^3}=
\left(\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)
\left(\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{a}\right)
\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)}$$

where all angles are unequal and between $0$ and $2\pi$.

I cannot work out the algebra on this problem.
This is a system of porsimatic equations. Meaning that it only has distinct solutions if some condition on the variables holds.

The method is the following, in the case of a chain of three equations,

$$a\cos\alpha\cos\beta+b\sin\alpha\sin\beta+c=0$$
$$a\cos\beta\cos\gamma+b\sin\beta\sin\gamma+c=0$$
$$a\cos\gamma\cos\alpha+b\sin\gamma\sin\alpha+c=0$$

We can show

$$\tan\frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{b}{a}\tan \gamma$$
either by setting an equation in variable $t$ with solutions, $\tan\frac{1}{2}\alpha$ and $\tan\frac{1}{2}\beta$ and using Vietas formulas or more straighforwardly solving for $\sin\gamma$ and $\cos\gamma$ to get $\tan\gamma$.

Similarly
$$\tan\frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\gamma)=\frac{b}{a}\tan \beta$$
$$\tan\frac{1}{2}(\gamma+\beta)=\frac{b}{a}\tan \alpha$$
and using these we get

$$\tan\frac{1}{2}(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{ab\sin(\alpha-\beta)}{a^2\cos\alpha\cos\beta+b^2\sin\alpha\sin\beta}$$ then using the definition of $\tan=\frac{\sin}{\cos}$ and dividing by $\sin\frac{1}{2}(\alpha-\beta)$ we see that

$$a\cos\alpha\cos\beta+b\sin\alpha\sin\beta+c=c-\frac{ab}{a+b}$$

In the case of a chain of five equations we get the fomulas,

$$\tan\frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\gamma)=\frac{b}{a}\tan\beta$$
$$\tan\frac{1}{2}(\beta+\delta)=\frac{b}{a}\tan\gamma$$
$$\tan\frac{1}{2}(\gamma+\epsilon)=\frac{b}{a}\tan\delta$$
$$\tan\frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\delta)=\frac{b}{a}\tan\epsilon$$
$$\tan\frac{1}{2}(\epsilon+\beta)=\frac{b}{a}\tan\alpha$$

But how to proceed from there ?

I guess you want  $\tan\frac{1}{2}(\alpha-\epsilon)
$ as a function of $\alpha$ and $\epsilon$.

Comment: Can you show how you got $\tan\frac{1}{2}(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{ab\sin(\alpha-\beta)}{a^2\cos\alpha\cos\beta+b^2\sin\alpha\sin\beta}$ from the previous?

Comment: @ACB Yeah, you let $\tan\frac{1}{2}(\alpha-\beta)=\tan\frac{1}{2}((\alpha+\gamma)-(\beta+\gamma))$ then you use the subtraction formula for $\tan$ along with the previous two formulas.

Comment: I think it should be $\tan\frac{1}{2}(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{ab\sin(\color{red}{\beta-\alpha})}{a^2\cos\alpha\cos\beta+b^2\sin\alpha\sin\beta}$ in the case of three equations, where you get $ab+bc+ca=0$ as it should be.

Comment: Have you got the answer? beacuse it seems to me that you are neglecting this post.

Comment: @ACB No I dont have an answer. I am still interested to see a solution. I have been thinking that I would put a bounty on this question.

Comment: I think that multiplying $3$ of the $5$ equations and then adding all of them together might get something. Allowing repetitions, this is $35$ equations; however, the $10$ coming from choice without repetitions added together gives coefficients of $a,b,c$ as elementary symmetric polynomials in the $\cos x_i, \sin x_i,s$. So do the $20$ choices with $2$ repetitions and finally the $5$ equations that are just cubing each individuals. I did the first one and it's already like a page and a half...

Comment: @user997661 No, I dont have a solution, but there are several methods available to someone who wants to solve it. First, there is the paper by wohlstenholme, mentioned below and in the book by Hobson. This paper, I think has essential a solution but in a more algebraic form. But more directly as in the case of three equations, one can deduce a second system with new coefficients, which are of the form $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{c}$. In the case of 3 equations this new system is the same as the old, comparing them gives the result (continued...)

Comment: (continued) In the case of five equation the new system with coefficients of the form in the part one of this comment, is not equivalent to the original system. However of one repeats the same transformation one does get the original system again. So by taking this transformation twice, and comparing with the system one should get an equation for the coefficients. In principle this is straightforward, but the algebraic manipulation is formidable.

Comment: I have spent a lot of time working on the general system of equations and therefore I am curious as to the context of the equations. That is, why did you consider these particular equations? Did they come from a geometric problem? Are they a generalization of a smaller set of equations? Are there are published references or links to where this came from?

Comment: @Somos , this is an exercise from "Treatise on Plane Trigonometry" by Hobson. By the way: Rene Schipperus, you have attached the tag '*contest-math'*. In which contest did this problem appear?

Comment: @Somo Yeah, thats where I got the problem from.  Its not contest math. It is really closer to tripos math questions, but this question is actually too difficult for that classification.  I cant possibly imagine any student solving this under any exam situation.

Comment: The exact reference is Hobson, 7th edition, Dover Publications reprint, on page 96, Examples on Chapter VI, top of the page, example 13. On pages 89-90 is article 73, _Porismatic systems of equations_ with a footnote to a paper on the topic by Wolstenholme in PLMS, Vol. IV.

Comment: The equations 2 and 3 should be permuted so the circular symmetry is clearer.  Great question in any case!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is we are ignoring the edge cases such as $\cos\theta = \pm\cos\phi,$ where $\theta,\phi$ are two angles among the given $5.$

$$(a\cos\alpha\cos\beta + c)^2 = b^2\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta\implies$$
The quadratic
$$f(t) = ((a^2-b^2)\cos^2\beta + b^2)t^2 + 2t\cdot (ac\cos\beta) + (c^2-b^2\sin^2\beta)$$
has roots $t = \cos\alpha$ and $t = \cos\gamma$ and thus:
$$\cos\alpha\cos\gamma = \dfrac{c^2-b^2\sin^2\beta}{a^2\cos^2\beta+b^2\sin^2\beta} = \dfrac{c^2\sec^2\beta-b^2\tan^2\beta}{a^2+b^2\tan^2\beta} = \dfrac{c^2 + (c^2-b^2)\tan^2\beta}{a^2+b^2\tan^2\beta}.$$

We use the identity derived in OP's text:
$$\tan\frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\gamma) = \dfrac{b}{a}\tan\beta,\quad (1)$$
to obtain:
$$\cos\alpha\cos\gamma = \dfrac{c^2+\frac{a^2(c^2-b^2)}{b^2}\left(\tan^2\dfrac{1}{2}(\alpha+\gamma)\right)}{a^2\left(1+\tan^2\dfrac{1}{2}(\alpha+\gamma)\right)}$$
and we can get rid of the square and half-angle above by using:
$$\tan^2x = \dfrac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x} = \dfrac{1-\cos 2x}{1+\cos 2x}.$$
Then we obtain the following:
$$\begin{align}
\cos\alpha\cos\gamma &= \dfrac{c^2+\dfrac{a^2(c^2-b^2)}{b^2}\cdot\dfrac{1-\cos(\alpha+\gamma)}{1+\cos(\alpha+\gamma)}}{a^2\left(1+\dfrac{1-\cos(\alpha+\gamma)}{1+\cos(\alpha+\gamma)}\right)} \\
&= \dfrac{c^2}{2a^2}(1+\cos(\alpha+\gamma))+\dfrac{c^2-b^2}{2b^2}(1-\cos(\alpha+\gamma))\quad (2)
\end{align}$$
Now, we do the spliting $\cos(\alpha+\gamma) = \cos\alpha\cos\gamma - \sin\alpha\sin\gamma$ and plug it into $(2)$, to finally obtain:
$$\left(\dfrac{1}{c^2} - \dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2}\right)\cos\alpha\cos\gamma+\left(\dfrac{1}{c^2} + \dfrac{1}{a^2}-\dfrac{1}{b^2}\right)\sin\alpha\sin\gamma + \left(\dfrac{1}{c^2} - \dfrac{1}{a^2}-\dfrac{1}{b^2}\right) = 0 \quad (3).$$

Now we can finish the problem by noting that the above "shifting" produces following chain of permutations:
$$(\alpha,\beta,\gamma, \delta,\epsilon)\longrightarrow (\alpha, \gamma, \epsilon, \beta, \delta) \longrightarrow (\color{red}{\alpha}, \epsilon, \delta, \color{red}{\gamma}, \color{red}{\beta})\longrightarrow\dots$$
This can go on for two more times but we have what we need from the third permutation above because this configuration also gives:
$$\dfrac{b_2}{a_2}\tan\beta = \tan\dfrac{\alpha+\gamma}{2} = \dfrac{b}{a}\tan\beta\iff \dfrac{b_2}{a_2} = \dfrac{b}{a},$$
where $b_2,a_2$ are the results of doing the transformation:
$$(a,b,c)\longrightarrow \left(\dfrac{1}{c^2}-\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2}, \dfrac{1}{c^2}+\dfrac{1}{a^2}-\dfrac{1}{b^2}, \dfrac{1}{c^2}-\dfrac{1}{a^2}-\dfrac{1}{b^2}\right)$$
twice. Here, let's reciprocate $a,b,c\to \frac 1a, \frac 1b, \frac 1c$ to simplify writing. This yields a big equation:
$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{a}{b} &= \dfrac{(c^2-a^2+b^2)^2(c^2+a^2-b^2)^2 + (c^2-a^2-b^2)^2\left((c^2+a^2-b^2)^2-(c^2-a^2+b^2)^2\right)}{(c^2-a^2+b^2)^2(c^2+a^2-b^2)^2 - (c^2-a^2-b^2)^2\left((c^2+a^2-b^2)^2-(c^2-a^2+b^2)^2\right)}\\
&=\dfrac{\left(c^4-(a^4-b^4)^2\right)^2+4c^2\left(c^2-a^2-b^2\right)^2(a^2-b^2)}{\left(c^4-(a^4-b^4)^2\right)^2-4c^2\left(c^2-a^2-b^2\right)^2(a^2-b^2)}
\end{align}$$
Subtract $1$ from both sides and factor out $(a-b)$ to give common denominator:
$$\begin{align}
\left(c^4-(a^4-b^4)^2\right)^2-4c^2\left(c^2-a^2-b^2\right)^2(a^2-b^2) = 8bc^2\left(c^2-a^2-b^2\right)^2(a+b)\implies \\
\left(c^4-(a^4-b^4)^2\right)^2 =4c^2(c^2-a^2-b^2)^2\left(a^2-b^2+2b(a+b)\right)\implies \\
(c^2-a^2+b^2)^2(c^2+a^2-b^2)^2 = 4c^2(a+b)^2(c^2-a^2-b^2)^2 \quad (4) 
\end{align}.$$

From here, if $c^2 = (a+b)^2,$ then we can notice that:
$$(c^2-a^2+b^2)^2(c^2+a^2-b^2)^2 = 16a^2b^2(a+b)^4 =4c^2(a+b)^2(c^2-a^2-b^2)^2, $$
meaning that we have a factor of $c^2-(a+b)^2$ in (4). Finally then $(4)$ factors as

$$(c^2-a^2+b^2)^2(c^2+a^2-b^2)^2 - 4c^2(a+b)^2(c^2-a^2-b^2)^2 = ((c^2-a^2+b^2)(c^2+a^2-b^2) - 2c(a+b)(c^2-a^2-b^2))\cdot ((c^2-a^2+b^2)(c^2+a^2-b^2) + 2c(a+b)(c^2-a^2-b^2)) = $$
$$ = (c-a-b)(a^3+b^3+c^3 - ab^2-a^2b-bc^2-b^2c - ca^2-c^2a-2abc)\cdot (c+a+b)(-a^3-b^3-c^3 + ab^2+a^2b+bc^2-b^2c - ca^2+c^2a-2abc) =0. $$

What's left now is to rule out the case $c\neq\pm (a+b)$ and then we will have one (or both) of only two options left:
$$a^3+b^3+c^3 = (a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$$ or
$$a^3+b^3-c^3 = (a+b)(b-c)(a-c).$$

Comment: Yes, I think this is the correct solution. I had come to the conclusion that it had to be like this. I am accepting your answer, I did not set the bounty so I cannot award that.

Comment: thanks. be nice to see a more motivated solution though. All the terms like $c^2\pm a^2\pm b^2$ are basically begging for some triangle geometry stuff.

Comment: @Flagged if you denote the original system as $$F(a,b,c,\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\epsilon) = 0,$$ 
then deriving above equation $(3)$ means that we have a new system 
$$F(a_1,b_1,c_1,\alpha, \gamma,\epsilon,\beta,\delta) = 0.$$
This will produce a new set of $5$ tangent relations derived in the OP's text but those are not useful because they are all new combinations such as:
$$\tan\frac{\alpha + \epsilon}{2} = \frac{b_1}{a_1}\tan\gamma.$$ But after doing the same thing to the new system again, the new system will be:
$$F(a_2,b_2,c_2,\alpha, \epsilon, \delta, \gamma,\beta) = 0.$$

Comment: In your answer, you use $\tan\frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\gamma) = \dfrac{b}{a}\tan\beta$ but this is valid only for "the case of a chain of three equations" and is **not** valid for a chain of five equations.

Comment: @Somos, no it is valid. perhaps you should grab a pen and paper derive it yourself.

Comment: Amazing! You are correct! Sorry about that. I should have easily checked for that.

Comment: @somos lol no worries. actually I just realized OP mentioned it in the question text.

Answer (score 4):

As Somos has thought, the problem is related to Poncelet's Porism.

It is equivalent that there's a pentagon inscribe in $\Gamma_1:x^2+y^2=1$ and circumscribe on $\Gamma_2: \frac{x^2}{c-b}+\frac{y^2}{c-a}+\frac{1}{a+b}=ux^2+vy^2+w=0$

Generally equation $ax_1x_2+by_1y_2+c=0$ means pointer $(x_1,y_1)$ is at polar of conic section $ax^2+by^2+c=0$ for point $(x_2,y_2)$. When point $(x_1,y_1)$ is moving in one conic section, the polar encloses another conic section (here the $ux^2+vy^2+w=0$.

For example, assume a line L is circumscribe on $\Gamma_2$ at $P_0(x_0,y_0)$ and intersection $\Gamma_1$ at $Q_1(x_1,y_1),Q_2(x_2,y_2)$, we have
$$\begin{cases}ux_0^2+vy_0^2+w=0\\ux_0x_1+vy_0y_1+w=0\\ux_0x_2+vy_0y_2+w=0\\x_1^2+y_1^2=1\\x_2^2+y_2^2=1\end{cases}$$
So we have $y_1=\frac{-w-ux_0x_1}{vy_0}$ and $x_1^2+\left(\frac{-w-ux_0x_1}{vy_0}\right)^2=1$, which means
$$(v^2y_0^2+u^2x_0^2)x_1^2+2wux_0x_1+w^2-v^2y_0^2=0$$
Similarly we have $(v^2y_0^2+u^2x_0^2)x_2^2+2wux_0x_2+w^2-v^2y_0^2=0$ so that $x_1,x_2$ are two roots of equation $(v^2y_0^2+u^2x_0^2)X^2+2wux_0X+w^2-v^2y_0^2=0$
By Vieta's formula we have $x_1x_2=\frac{w^2-v^2y_0^2}{v^2y_0^2+u^2x_0^2}$
With similar approach we have $y_1y_2=\frac{w^2-u^2x_0^2}{v^2y_0^2+u^2x_0^2}$.
So $ax_1x_2+by_1y_2+c=\frac{(a+b)w^2+(c-a)v^2y_0^2+(c-b)u^2x_0^2}{v^2y_0^2+u^2x_0^2}=\frac{w+vy_0^2+ux_0^2}{v^2y_0^2+u^2x_0^2}=0$.

According to Poncelet's Porism, we could start from any points in $\Gamma_1$ to form the pentagon ABCDE so that we could choose $\alpha=0$ which is equivalent that A(1,0). so $\cos(\beta)=\cos(\epsilon)=-\frac ca$ which shows that $B(-\frac ca, \frac{\sqrt{a^2-c^2}}a),E(-\frac ca,-\frac{\sqrt{a^2-c^2}}a)$.
By symmetric, we have CD circumscribes on $\Gamma_2$ at $(h,0)=(\pm\sqrt{-\frac{w}{u}},0)$ so $h^2=-\frac wu=\frac{b-c}{a+b}$ so $C(h,\sqrt{1-h^2}), D(h,-\sqrt{1-h^2})$ or $C(h,-\sqrt{1-h^2}), D(h,\sqrt{1-h^2})$ or $\cos(\gamma)=\cos(\delta)=h$
Since $a\cos(\beta)\cos(\gamma)+b\sin(\beta)\sin(\gamma)+c=0$
we have $b^2\sin^2(\beta)\sin^2(\gamma)=(-c-a\cos(\beta)\cos(\gamma))^2$ that's
$$b^2(1-\frac{c^2}{a^2})(1-h^2)=c^2(1-h)^2$$
or
$$\frac{1-h}{1+h}=\frac{b^2}{c^2}(1-\frac{c^2}{a^2})$$
or
$$\frac{b-c}{a+b}=h^2=\left(\frac{b^2a^2-b^2c^2-a^2c^2}{b^2a^2-b^2c^2+a^2c^2}\right)^2$$

Finally we could simplify the formula into
$$(a-b)^2(a+b)c^3+ab(a+b)^2c^2-a^2b^2(a+b)c-a^3b^3=0$$
or we could rewrite it as
$$ \frac1{a^3}+\frac1{b^3}-\frac1{c^3}=(\frac1a+\frac1b)(\frac1a-\frac1c)(\frac1b-\frac1c)$$

Now we could choose some data to verify the formula. For example a=2, c=1, b=1.0356563731256918583980883131742380541 satisfy formula above (but not for that of
dezdichado
)
and we could construct one of the root as below

$$\begin{cases}
\alpha=0&\cos(\alpha)=1&\sin(\alpha)=0\\
\beta=2.0943951023931954923084289221863352561&\cos(\beta)=-0.5&\sin(\beta)=-0.47942553860420300027328793521557138809\\
\gamma=-1.4622047455839744317084407839834855485&\cos(\gamma)=0.10837828597562565035637625724555457401&\sin(\gamma)=-0.99410972590000622348950262653193401668\\
\delta=1.4622047455839744317084407839834855480&\cos(\delta)=0.10837828597562565035637625724555457446&\sin(\delta)=0.99410972590000622348950262653193401663\\
\epsilon=-2.0943951023931954923084289221863352561&\cos(\epsilon)=-0.5&\sin(\epsilon)=-0.86602540378443864676372317075293618346
\end{cases}$$

Comment: this looks neat.

Comment: Interesting, I will have to look into this.

Answer (score 3):

(Not a solution. Too long to be a comment. Maybe there are some ideas here to use.)

Let $ \cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha = A $ and similar equations for the rest.
Then, we have $ a ( A + \frac{1}{A} ) ( B + \frac{1}{B} ) - b ( A - \frac{1}{A} ) ( B - \frac{1}{B} ) + 4c = 0 $, and similar.
Clearing denominators gives  $ a( A^2 + 1) ( B^2 + 1 ) - b ( A^2 - 1) ( B^2 - 1) + 4cAB = 0 $, and similar.

For a fixed $A$, view this as a quadratic in $B$:

$$ B^2 [ (a-b)A^2 + (a+b)] + B [ 4Ac ] + [(a+b)A^2 + (a-b) ] = 0 $$

Since $B, E$ are distinct roots of this quadratic, we may apply Vieta's to obtain $ B+E, BE$, and similar equations.

Comment: Thanks for that +1. Actually have have just come to this conclusion myself, using the complex expression may simplify the pain.  I have just dug up some of the old articles which form the basis for this question. So maybe that will help.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus it was a fun problem to look at, though I'm sad it didn't lead anywhere as yet. It's not immediately clear to me how to proceed from here, since even finding the symmetric polynomials isn't that easy (though that's what I would have done for the much simpler 3-variable case).

Comment: The result of that manipulation is precisely [this paper by Joseph Wolestenholme](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s1-4.1.312).

Comment: Yea it's a "standard" manipulation (for those in the know). However, a lot easier for 3 variables (since you can set $B+C = q_1 - A$)".

Comment: @user10354138 Is it possible to obtain a (free) online copy of the paper by Wolestenholme?

Comment: @user2661923 Given Wolestenholme died in 1891, the work should be in "public domain" 70 years after his death.  You can get a free (gratis) copy from sci-hub completely legally in this case, but be warned that copy isn't of the best quality.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 3):

This is only a small correction to the question statement, but is still too long for the usual comment format. You probably forgot to include the condition that no two of the angles are opposites. Otherwise, there are several simple enough counterexamples, such as the following one.
For simplicity, I write $\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_5$ instead of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\epsilon$, and I also put $c_k=\cos(\theta_k),s_k=\sin(\theta_k)$. The counterexample has $a=-1,b=c=1$ (so $a^{-3}+b^{-3}+c^{-3}=1 \neq 0 = (a^{-1}+b^{-1})(a^{-1}+c^{-1})(b^{-1}+c^{-1})$)

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
k & c_k & s_k & c_kc_{k+1} & s_ks_{k+1} \\
\hline
1 & -\frac{35}{37} & -\frac{12}{37} & \frac{1925}{2701} & -\frac{576}{2701} \\
\hline
2 & -\frac{55}{73} & \frac{48}{73} & -\frac{275}{949} & \frac{576}{949} \\
\hline
3 & \frac{5}{13} & \frac{12}{13} & -\frac{3}{13} & -\frac{48}{65} \\
\hline
4 & -\frac{3}{5} & -\frac{4}{5} & \frac{21}{37} & -\frac{48}{185} \\
\hline
5 & -\frac{35}{37} & \frac{12}{37} & \frac{1225}{1369} & -\frac{144}{1369} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: it seems you have some algorithm generating this "counter-example" only consisting of rational pythagoran triples. Could you modify so it actually give an example of $a,b,c,d,e$ and the angles that solve the equation ?

Comment: @dezdichado I found no rational solutions so far. Merely finding rational (and nonzero) $a,b,c$ with $a^{-3}+b^{-3}+c^{-3} = (a^{-1}+b^{-1})(a^{-1}+c^{-1})(b^{-1}+c^{-1})$ does not seem easy, at least to me.

Answer (score 2):

### NOTE: This answer is obsolete. My new answer is below.

I had originally thought that this question is very similar to other
porisms such as [Poncelet's closure theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poncelet%27s_closure_theorem). After some more work, I think that
it is more similar to non-linear recursions such as the generalized
Lyness recursion. That is $\,x_n = (a+x_{n-1})/x_{n-2}\,$ where $\,a\,$
is a fixed constant. If $\,a=1\,$ the sequence is 5-periodic no matter
what the initial values $\,a_0,a_1\,$ are. If $\,a=0\,$ the sequence is
6-periodic. Otherwise, the period (if any) depends on the initial values.
I think that something similar holds for the system of equations in the
question.

This answer is not yet a complete solution but is a promising approach.

As motivation, consider the trigonometric identities

$$ 4\, t(x)t(y)t(z) = t(-x-y-z) + t(-x+y+z) + t(+x-y+z) + t(+x+y-z) $$

which holds for both $\,t = \sin\,$ and $\,t = \cos.\,$

Thus, define the trigonometric functions:

$$ f(x) := \sin(x+\pi/4) = (\sin(x)+\cos(x))/\sqrt{2} $$

and

$$ F(x,y,z) := (f(-x-y-z) + f(-x+y+z) + f(+x-y+z) + f(+x+y-z))/\sqrt{8}. $$

Notice that $\,F\,$ is fully symmetric and, in general, every equation
$\, F(x,y,z) = t \,$ has two solutions for each of $\,x,y,z\,$
given the other three variables.

The question about the system of equation can be reformulated.

Consider two sequences of real numbers $\,x_n\,$ and $\,w_n\,$ such that the fundamental equation

$$ c_k := F(x_n,x_{n+k},w_k) $$

depends only on $\,k.\,$ Notice that the $\,\{x_0,x_1,\dots\}\,$
correspond to the $\,\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\dots\}\,$ of the
question  while $\,(\cos(w_1),\sin(w_1),-c_1)\,$ corresponds to $\,(a,b,c).\,$

Such sequences can be constructed by recursion. Start with
values of $\,x_0,x_1,w_1\,$ and where
$\, c_1 =F(x_0,x_1,w_1).\,$ With the
given values of $\,x_1,w_1,c_1\,$ there are two solutions of
$\, c_1 = F(x,x_1,w_1).$ One solution is $\,x_0\,$ and define $\,x_2\,$
to be the other solution. This provides a recursion for the sequence
$\,x_n\,$ where given $\,x_{n-2}\,$ and $\,x_{n-1}\,$ the $\,x_n\,$ is
the solution of an equation.

Now the problem is to show that there exists $\,c_2\,$ and $\,w_2\,$
such that the fundamental equation holds. So far, I have a computer
algebra proof of this result. Even more challenging is to prove the
fundamental equation for general $\,k>2.\,$

Note that $\,c_0 = 1/\sqrt{2}, w_0 = \pi/4.\,$ Suppose that $\,w_1\,$ is such
that $\,w_N = w_0\,$ for some positive $\,N.\,$ Then the $\,x_n\,$
sequence is periodic with period $\,N\,$ but this depends on the initial
values $\,x_0,x_1.\,$

The question posed is the special where $\,N=5.\,$

---

### EDIT: new answer

My initial guess was correct about the Poncelet porism. The exact source reference for the question is Hobson, *Treatise on Plane Trigonometry*,
7th edition, Dover Publications reprint, on page $96$, Examples on Chapter
VI, top of the page, example $13$. On pages $89\!-\!90$ is article $73$, Porismatic systems of equations with a footnote to a paper on the topic by
Wolstenholme in PLMS, Vol. IV.

On the topic of Poncelet's porism I read the work by Jakob Rosanes and
Moritz Pasch published in $1869$ in Crelle's journal on pages $169$ to $174$. The very first equation on page $169$

$$ f(t_0,t_1) = at_0^2t_1^2 + 2bt_0t_1(t_0+t_1) + c(t_0+t_1)^2 +
2dt_0t_1 + 2e(t_0+t_1) + f = 0 $$

is sometimes called a "biquadratic relation" or "Euler-Chasles correspondence". The first term is used by Rodney Baxter in Chapter
15 of *Exactly Solved Models in Statistical Mechanics*. The second
is used by Ivan Izmestiev in arXiv:1501.07157, *Deformation of
Quadrilaterals and Addition on Elliptic Curves*. Both references
mention the parametrization of the equation by elliptic functions.
This goes back to Jacobi himself in the context of Poncelet's porism
for two circles. However, the use of elliptic functions is not needed.

The first equation in this questions is

$$ a\cos\alpha\cos\beta+b\sin\alpha\sin\beta+c=0. $$

Use the half-angle substitutions

$$ \cos\alpha = \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2},\:\: \sin\alpha = \frac{2x}{1+x^2},
\:\: \cos\beta = \frac{1-y^2}{1+y^2},\:\: \sin\beta = \frac{2y}{1+y^2} $$

to transform the equation into

$$ a\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\frac{1-y^2}{1+y^2}
  +b\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\frac{2y}{1+y^2} + c = 0. $$

Clear denominators and expand to get

$$ f_1(x,y) := (a+c)x^2y^2 +(c-a)(x^2+y^2) +4bxy + (a+c) = 0. $$

In general, there is a sequence of biquadratic relations

$$ f_n(x,y) := u_n(x^2y^2 + 1) + v_n(x^2+y^2) + w_n(xy) = 0 $$

such that $\,f_n(x,y) = 0\,$ and $\,f_m(y,z) = 0\,$ is equivalent to
$\,f_{n+m}(x,z) = 0\,$ which can be proven using polynomial resultants
eliminating the variable $y$.

Calculations with Mathematica show that $\,f_3(x,x)\,$ has a factor of
$$ (ab-bc-ac)^2 = (abc)^2(1/a+1/b+1/c)^2.$$
Also $\,f_4(x,x)\,$ has a factor of $\,abc.\,$ Finally, $\,f_5(x,x)\,$
has a factor of

$$ (a^3 b^3+a^3 b^2 c-a^3 b c^2-a^3 c^3+a^2 b^3 c-2 a^2 b^2 c^2+a^2 b c^3-a b^3 c^2+a b^2 c^3-b^3 c^3)^2 $$

which can be written as

$$ (abc)^6 \left(-\Big(\frac1{a^3}+\frac1{b^3}-\frac1{c^3}\Big)+
   \Big(\frac1b-\frac1c\Big)\Big(-\frac1c+\frac1a\Big)\Big(\frac1a+\frac1b\Big)\right)^2. $$

Thus, for a chain of $3$ equations the condition is

$$ \frac1{a}+\frac1{b}+\frac1{c} = 0 $$

and for a chain of $5$ equations as in the original question it is

$$\frac1{a^3}+\frac1{b^3}-\frac1{c^3} = \Big(\frac1b-\frac1c\Big)
\Big(-\frac1c+\frac1a\Big)\Big(\frac1a+\frac1b\Big). $$

Notice that from the [Poncelet Porism](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PonceletsPorism.html) MathWorld page, given that $\,R\,$ is the
cimcumradius, $\,r\,$ is the inraidus, and $\,d\,$ is the distance
between the circumcenter and incenter, then define

$$ a := \frac1{R+d}, \qquad b := \frac1{R-d}, \qquad c := \frac1r. $$

The condition for a triangle is $\, a+b=c \,$ and for a pentagon it is

$$ a^3+b^2+c^3 = (a+b)(b+c)(c+a) $$

which are very similar to the conditions for the question equations